# "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" in IntelliJ and JBoss Dev Studio and mvn on commandline on Mac for TestNG test

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, connection, firewall

I have a Java functional TestNG test which is hitting a REST API endpoint.

Same test worked on Windows PC with IntelliJ and JBoss with no special settings.

I can hit this endpoint in Postman, so I know it's up/alive.

We made a simple Node Express server / Java ping program that listens on various ports (e.g. in the 6xxxx range) and replies if the ping was successful. This works.

But in IntelliJ and JBoss Dev Studio IDEs AND on mvn test commandline on Mac, it fails immediately, doesn't even touch any of my test code, and I get:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60329', transport: 'socket'
[TestNG] Running:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
```

...

```
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
```

I've tried a few things with no luck:

1. Allow IntelliJ in firewall, and even turn off Mac firewall completely
2. java.net.preferIPv4Stack in VM options and in Info.plist for IntelliJ in case it was an IPv6 thing
3. Auto-detect proxy settings in IntelliJ settings (never had to do this on Windows IntelliJ, but just to make sure)
4. Debugger > Transport > Shared memory (actually it won't let me select this at the moment, but one web page suggested this as a fix)

Versions:

- IntelliJ 2016.2
- Java 1.7.0_79
- Mac 10.11.5

Answer (score 0):

​Well, I ended up deleting my entire set of Git repos and starting over from scratch. My TestNG tests are now running. Why that worked? I have no idea. Just glad to get back to work.